# Как взаимодействовать с сайтом через Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование

Имеется задача, которую нужно сделать на Python 3:

```
1. Вставить какое-либо значение в поле для ввода на сайте (строка поиска например)
2. Нажать на кнопку (например кнопка "поиск")
3. Получить загрузившуюся страничку
```

В каких библиотеках это реализовано и вообще возможно ли это?

Comment: используйте selenium

Comment: Что за сайт? Возможно это можно сделать через отправку доп. данных на сайт. Оставьте ссылку.

Comment: https://1wuoy.top/profile Там есть поле "ваучер", перед этим зарегистрируйтесь, там есть функция "регистрация в 1 клик".

Comment: Можно через браузер, можно запросами через requests